# Googlebot couldn't crawl this URL because it points to a non-existent page

Tags: php, google-search-console, google-crawlers

Googlebot couldn't crawl this URL because it points to a non-existent page. Generally, 404s don't harm your site's performance in search, but you can use them to help improve the user experience. 
this error occur in following urls.

how can i solve it..[image]

Comment: Are you sure the pages actually exist?

Comment: this all page is not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check and see which page **links** to these pages. maybe your website's domain had a previous owner who had a webpage, and there are some inbound links pointing to that old website. this is something you can't control, if thats the case you should do a redirect on these pages to your start page. Do this with your `.htaccess` file:

`ErrorDocument 404 /index.html`

some things to check that may produce malformed urls and is under your control:

- your *paging* code in search results and/or categories of products/services/content
- your sitemap

i also had a similar experience, in one of my websites i had this scheme:

`example.com?category=1`

`example.com?category=2`

`example.com?category=3`

and in webmaster tools i was getting random strings:

`example.com?category=xxcCzxvsd`

in my analytics nobody (except googlebot) ever visited `example.com?category=xxcCzxvsd`. I couldn't find the source of this, so there is a strong chance the problem is in google's side.